# CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND

Tags: linux, cmake, configure

I am trying to configure the `whalebot` crawler with the tar file `whalebot-0.02.00.tar.gz`. I have extracted it correctly with:

```
root@Admin1:~/dls# tar xvzf whalebot-0.02.00.tar.gz
```

After that I want to configure it with:

```
root@Admin1:~/dls/whalebot# ./configure
```

It gives me error:

> bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

also I have run the command:

```
root@Admin1:~/dls/whalebot# cmake ./
```

It gives me the following result:

```
root@Admin1:~/dls/whalebot# cmake ./
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Boost version: 1.44.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
-- filesystem
-- system
-- thread
-- program_options
-- date_time
CMake Warning (dev) at webspider/CMakeLists.txt:25 (link_directories):
This command specifies the relative path

../statsem_string/bin

as a link directory.

Policy CMP0015 is not set: link_directories() treats paths relative to the
source dir. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0015" for policy details. Use the
cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at webspider/CMakeLists.txt:25 (link_directories):
This command specifies the relative path

../3dparty/google-url

as a link directory.

Policy CMP0015 is not set: link_directories() treats paths relative to the
source dir. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0015" for policy details. Use the
cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
HTMLCXX_LIBRARY
linked by target "whalebot" in directory /root/dls/whalebot/webspider

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that CMake is unable to find the htmlcxx library.

In the [whalebot documentation](http://code.google.com/p/whalebot/wiki/GettingStarted), htmlcxx is listed as a dependency.

You need to [download htmlcxx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlcxx/), unzip it, then install it:

```
cd <path to unzipped htmlcxx>
./configure --enable-static=on --enable-shared=off
make
sudo make install
```

You may need to add `#include <cstddef>` to the top of `html/tree.h` to get it to build successfully.  It will install to `usr/local/` by default.

You also need [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/) installed if you don't already have it:

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

Finally, you can now build and install whalebot.  Again, making might fail if you have a reasonably up-to-date boost installation.

In line 57 of `webspider/src/webspider_options.cpp`, you need to replace `boost::filesystem::initial_path().native_directory_string()` with `boost::filesystem::initial_path().string()`.  Then you should be good to build and install:

```
cd <path to unzipped whalebot>
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make
sudo make install
```

This too will install to `usr/local/` by default.

Comment: how can i attach that htmlcxx library, i am new to linux so please don´t mind **thnx**

Comment: thanks for help, it is working now and the build was successful. now after the build what is next step to run the whalebot...

Comment: @MuhammadAssad Glad it works.  Regarding usage of whalebot, you should be able to execute it just by entering `whalebot` in a command prompt with the appropriate arguments.  If you have problems with or queries about its usage, again I'd refer you to the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/whalebot/wiki/GettingStarted) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/whalebot/wiki/CommandLineParameters).

Comment: thanks for help.basically i need to integrate this whalebot crawler in my search engine project which will be implemented in C#.net. there fore 1st i am going to compile and configure whalebot and then integrate with search engine project which will be implemented in C#.net...

Answer (score 2):

Check if in CMakeLists you have written `find_library(..)` or `find_path(.)`, then replace it by `find_package(..)`.

It solved the error in my case.