# Cmake Error: The following variables are used in the project, but they are set to NOTFOUND trying to compile Rigs of Rods in archlinux

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, cmake, archlinux

I've been trying to compile Rigs of Rods under archlinux with 4.2.6 Kernel.
I've followed the official compiling instructions presented in http://www.rigsofrods.com/wiki/pages/Compiling_Sources_under_Linux
I have succesfully compiled ogredeps and CMake gave me no error, I even enabled multithreading for it (while using make, after running CMake .), but when I try to compile Ogre (Mentioned under the "Ogre Itself" section in compiling instructions) CMake gives me this:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OIS_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /root/ror-deps/ogre/Samples
   used as include directory in directory /root/ror-deps/ogre/Samples
   used as include directory in directory /root/ror-deps/ogre/Samples
   used as include directory in directory /root/ror-deps/ogre/Samples
   used as include directory in directory /root/ror-deps/ogre/Samples
   used as include directory in directory /root/ror-deps/ogre/Samples
   used as include directory in directory /root/ror-deps/ogre/Samples
   used as include directory in directory /root/ror-deps/ogre/Samples
```

Also here is the output of /root/ror-deps/ogre/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log:

```
Determining if the system is big endian passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/ror-deps/ogre/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_4b356/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_4b356.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_4b356.dir/build
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/root/ror-deps/ogre/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4b356.dir/TestEndianess.c.o
/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_4b356.dir/TestEndianess.c.o   -c /root/ror-deps/ogre/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/TestEndianess.c
Linking C executable cmTC_4b356
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_4b356.dir/link.txt  --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_4b356.dir/TestEndianess.c.o  -o cmTC_4b356 -rdynamic 
 make[1]: se sale del directorio '/root/ror-deps/ogre/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

TestEndianess.c:
/* A 16 bit integer is required. */
typedef unsigned short cmakeint16;

/* On a little endian machine, these 16bit ints will give "THIS IS LITTLE ENDIAN."
   On a big endian machine the characters will be exchanged pairwise. */
 const cmakeint16 info_little[] =  {0x4854, 0x5349, 0x4920, 0x2053, 0x494c, 0x5454, 0x454c, 0x4520, 0x444e, 0x4149, 0x2e4e, 0x0000};

/* on a big endian machine, these 16bit ints will give "THIS IS BIG ENDIAN."
   On a little endian machine the characters will be exchanged pairwise. */
const cmakeint16 info_big[] =     {0x5448, 0x4953, 0x2049, 0x5320, 0x4249, 0x4720, 0x454e, 0x4449, 0x414e, 0x2e2e, 0x0000};

#ifdef __CLASSIC_C__
int main(argc, argv) int argc; char *argv[];
#else
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
#endif
{
  int require = 0;
  require += info_little[argc];
  require += info_big[argc];
  (void)argv;
  return require;
}
```

I've researched, I've taken a look at these questions:

-[CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949153/cmake-error-the-following-variables-are-used-in-this-project-but-they-are-set)
-[CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717798/cmake-error-the-following-variables-are-used-in-this-project-but-they-are-set)
-[CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND ? in ros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031444/cmake-error-the-following-variables-are-used-in-this-project-but-they-are-set)

but either they refer to different issues or simply I can't understand the answers well

Comment: OIS_INCLUDE_DIR means that the includes (header files) of OIS are not found. Either your distribution has a package which you have to install or you have to add the OIS install directory to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

Comment: Thank you, I removed and re-installed ois (object-oriented input system) and now I'm able to generate makefiles using cmake, However I'm stuck at make; It gives me this both if I use make or mke -j4 to enble multithreading:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OIS_INCLUDE_DIR` means that the includes (header files) of OIS are not found. Either your distribution has a package which you have to install or you have to add the OIS install directory to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Comment: Thank you, I've downloaded and compiled OIS and now i'm able to use CMake, but i'm stuck at make, however, I will open a new question for that issue